# PHPMyAdmin - Create New Admin account for website

Tags: phpmyadmin, cal

I am attempting to add an **admin user** to our website, and none of the credentials work. My goal is to add an adminstrator by creating a query, and mostly all websites I have found are for wordpresses.

My prefix is **"cal_users"**, not **"wp_users"**. I need help, and if someone were to give me the code to copy and paste for the query that would be wonderful. I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Chase!  Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on crafting a good question.  In this case you should be more specific about what you've tried and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

it must be something like this

```
update 'cal_usermeta' 
set meta_value='a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}', meta_value='10' 
where meta_key='wp_capabilities' 
and meta_key='wp_user_level' 
and user_id='[ID from cal_user]';
```

remember to change the userID

Comment: is that the exact code for the query i will use? i just want the exact code to copy and paste so i can hit go.

Comment: without the user id it´s hard, you need the user id

Comment: honestly, i've been assigned this project as a learning tool. So, if i seem clueless, i kind of am. so how do i find the user id?

Comment: do   "select * from cal_user" the first col is call ID

Comment: the user id is just a number. so i can choose any user i want, and give them administrator privilges?

Comment: yup. with that number in the script you must gave him administrator privilges

Comment: can you make the code for me so i can just copy and paste it? i'm sorry, i'm just new to this.

Comment: sure I can, but i need the user ID

Comment: the username is     MattDickinson                the id is          2

Comment: update 'cal_usermeta' 
set meta_value='a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}', meta_value='10' 
where meta_key='wp_capabilities' 
and meta_key='wp_user_level' 
and user_id='2';

Comment: is the code you told me to copy and paste the only thing i need to do? and by the way i appreciate all your help

Answer (score -1):

copy and paste this

```
update cal_usermeta set meta_value='a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}', meta_value='10' where meta_key='wp_capabilities' and meta_key='wp_user_level' and user_id='2';
```

Comment: wait, i've a cuestion. do you need this for a wordpress site or only to manage phpmyadmin? bc this code works for wordpress

Comment: ill send you the link i need to get into. its a website, not phpmyadmin

Comment: thats not a wordpress site, is someone makeit in node.js or angular.js i can't help you with that, unless you showme how is the database, but that is a security breach and you can lost your work in that way

Comment: so how do i add an adminstrative account to it though?

Comment: IDK, in the admin panel it must been a user list and you can mod it there

Comment: by admin panel do you mean once i login inside the link i gave you

Comment: the same link / place

Comment: Please learn to *edit your answer* instead of posting multiple variants on the same thread.  One answer per question is the SO ideal.